Bathroom sinks are draining slowly
Sinks are draining slowly. They start to accumulate easily

Do I have to replace plumbing below sink?

Is more than one sink involved? Picture shows only one. Is this a new problem or sink always drained slowly? We need more information.

Probably you just need to clean the accumulated hair and other stuff ("clog" generically, it's almost always hair-based) from the pipes. How far would depend on how far it's clogged. You should not have to replace any pipes, but you might need to disassemble some to clean them out, and potentially to provide access for a plumber's snake to clean the pipes beyond the easily disassembled under-sink piping.
Minor warning: It's generally pretty disgusting. And you should plug the drain if you remove the trap except while you are actually snaking the drain, to minimize sewer gas entering the house. A plastic bag held over the end with a rubber band is typically adequate for that. You'll want some sort of bucket for dumping the trap water into, and a trash can for the glop that comes out of the pipes. Or put the disassembled pipes into the bucket and take outside to hose them clean.
One of my lavatories (sinks) has a stopper that's particularly good at catching hair and generating a local clog on the bottom of the stopper. Usually simply removing the stopper and that mass of hair will restore it to draining properly (with no pipe disassembly at all.)
A so-called "hair snake" may likewise permit removing hair it can reach without needing to disassemble the drain.
